# Swift Realm: how to handling error when add new object with same primary key?

Tags: swift, realm

I'm using RealmSwift in my project. (I'm new to realm)
when I want to add new object with same primary key, my app crashed with this error:

**Attempting to create an object of type 'Card' with an existing primary key value.**

how I can handling this error without crashing.
this is my model codes:

```
class Card: Object, Decodable {

    @objc dynamic var pan           = ""
    @objc dynamic var title         = ""

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return CodingKeys.pan.stringValue
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case pan
        case title
    }

    required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    
        self.pan        = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .pan)
        self.title      = ""
    }
}
```

and this is my database manager codes:

```
class DatabaseRequest {

    func addCard(_ card: Card) -> Bool {
    
        let realm = try! Realm()
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(card)
            }
            return true
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

i have been seeing some solution like check object with same primary key is exist before adding it to database.

why this part of code never executed and what is it for?

```
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
        return false
    }
```

Comment: Primary keys are unique, meaning that you cannot, and shouldn't try to add another object that has the same primary key. There is no solution as you can't do that. Can you explain why you want two objects with the same primary key? Also, this is not a primary key `return CodingKeys.pan.stringValue` wheras this is `return pan`. See the Realm guide [Primary Keys](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys). We can probably help with the modeling but need more info - update the question please.

Comment: Also, it's also common practice to allow realm/swift to assign primary keys to objects automatically - then you don't have to worry about handling them as they will always be unique. A common pattern is to set the primary key value to NSUUID().UUIDString to generate unique string IDs. So it would look like `@objc dynamic var my_primary_key = NSUUID().UUIDString`

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `update` property is `.error`, which means that you will get an error when you try to create or add an object with the same primary key.

To prevent this, just set `update` property to `.modifed` or `.all`

`realm.add(card, update: .all)`

Comment: `realm.add(card, update: .all)` will update all properties, even if it nil. For you, it will look like you create a new object with the same primary key.

Comment: that's good,  but why catch part was never executed?

Comment: The OP isn't attempting to update the object so this answer won't apply (although it's on point for updating an existing object!)